# Mongoose unable to find By ObjectId reference

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema of RoomSchema like below

```
{
  .....
  venue_details : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'VenueDetail'}
  .....
}
```

When I'm searching with one of the ObjectIds that I am having with me in mongodb system console it is giving correct result for below query.

```
db.rooms.find({venue_details: "576a6aa52edadbba50ff0944"})
```

But whne I'm searching inside the mongoose. I'm getting an empty array.

```
Room.find({venue_details: new ObjectId("576a69c32edadbba50ff093e")},function(err, docs){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
  console.log(docs);}
})
```

I've tried putting `ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId` , also `ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`, and also `ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

Even tried just putting String in the place of  `new ObjectId("576a69c32edadbba50ff093e")` just like `"576a69c32edadbba50ff093e"`. Even it is not working.

I'm using mongoose V 4.4.1, and MongoDB V 3.2.7

Comment: Did you initially create or populate the database with another schema (where `venue_details` was of type `String`)?

Comment: I used populate for the same Room Schema. Populate is working fine. But I don't know why this is not working!

Comment: It looks like the `venue_details` in the database is of type `String`, which is unexpected with the schema that you're showing. Because of the schema, Mongoose will cast query properties to `ObjectId`, which is why it may not work. However, question is: why is it a string in your database?

Comment: I got it. I have inserted into db manually. How can I convert it into ObjectId()

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10289547/893780), specifically the `db.foo.find().forEach(...)` command used there.

Comment: it solved my problem. @robertklep thank you.!