# Change _id value from a number to ObjectId()?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (510 documents) where _id are numbers :

```
{    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "eric" }

{    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "tom" }
....
```

and I want to change their values to ObjectId() to be like this:

```
{    "_id" : ObjectId("53849e258bf3be07804a00d0"),
    "name" : "eric" }

{    "_id" : ObjectId("53849e388bf3be07804a00d1"),
    "name" : "tom" }
....
```

so I tried:

```
db.contacts.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    db.contacts.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "_id": ObjectId()} }
    );
    })
```

but it doesn't work, I got like result:

```
Mod on _id not allowed
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the `_id` of an Object in a collection once it is created (it is not allowed by mongodb at all). However you could copy the full content of the object execpt of the `_id` and add your new `_id` with the `ObjectId` and insert it into your collection. Afterwards you can remove all the Objects where the `_id` is a number. It's a bit more complicated but the result is the same (and it works).

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4012997/1515052).