# update _id in mongodb for entire collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

New in mongodb, my requirement is to update the _id field for entire collection as follows:

orignal : `_id: ObjectId("4cc45467c55f4d2d2a000002")`

required: `_id: 4cc45467c55f4d2d2a000002`

I want to truncate 'ObjectId("' from beginning and '")' from end of all documents from whole collection.

Moreover I have seen following on a similar post but its all manual I have millions of rows/document wish to have a function or some thing to do it of all document.

```
// store the document in a variable
doc = db.clients.findOne({_id: ObjectId("4cc45467c55f4d2d2a000002")})
// set a new _id on the document
doc._id = ObjectId("4c8a331bda76c559ef000004")
// insert the document, using the new _id
db.clients.insert(doc)
// remove the document with the old _id
db.clients.remove({_id: ObjectId("4cc45467c55f4d2d2a000002")})
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you required to do this? MongoDB uses the ObjectID object in order to identify records.

Comment: I dont think you can manipulate the default id of a document. As it states, it is an Object id which mongodb creates to uniquely identity each document inside a collection. However, you can create your own id in case you want to customize it. And you can generate that id somewhat similar to what mongo generates by default using various combinations of host, server, time, date, etc.    OR if you want the same content, you can go by your method. Fetch object id, then Object_id.valueOf() and then update that document

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  The `ObjectId("` and `")` parts that you're looking to remove aren't actually in your docs; they're just shown as type information in the shell when you query it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How update the \_id of one MongoDB Document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 0):

MongodDB does not allow a modification of the `_id` field at all. So once you created a document you cannot change the `_id`s value.

The error message if you try to update the `_id` is: `Mod on _id not allowed`

If you want to do a change to the value of `_id` (as you already found) you have to copy your document to a variable, change the `_id`, insert the new document and delete the old one. There is no other way.