# Delete all docs of type ObjectId as _id field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my collection I have few docs with some having `_id` field as string and some others as type ObjectId

```
{_id:"xxxx"}
{_id:"yyyy"}
{_id:"ObjectId(zzz)"}
{_id:"ObjectId(xxxssssx)"}
```

I want to delete _id field type ObjectId(here last docs)

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your document has `ObjectId` you can use `$type`

For Example if your collection is like

```
{
    "_id" : "foo"
}


{
    "_id" : "bar"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c52074e418d78ff419897")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546c52074e418d78ff419898")
}
```

Remove Only ObjectId

`db.coll.remove({_id:{$type:7}})`

if your ObjectId is like

```
{_id:"ObjectId(zzz)"}
{_id:"ObjectId(xxxssssx)"}
```

you can do it

`db.coll.remove({"_id": {$regex:"^ObjectId"}})`

if you want delete only one Document

`db.coll.remove({"_id": {$regex:"^ObjectId"}},{justOne:true})`

obviously, a specific _id

```
db.coll.remove({"_id" : "ObjectId(xxxssssx)"})
```

Comment: When I run `db.coll.remove({_id:{$type:7}})` all the docs in the collection are deleted, I have backup though :)

Comment: @iAmME with `db.coll.remove({_id:{$type:7}})` remove Only ObjectId http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/.Maybe you have write wrong. With your documents, nothing is deleted, because they aren't "real" `ObjectId` but they are `string`

Comment: With your documents `{_id:"xxxx"}
{_id:"yyyy"}
{_id:"ObjectId(zzz)"}
{_id:"ObjectId(xxxssssx)"}`, nothing is deleted. Then you have to use `$regex`

Answer (score 0):

For deleting object you should write in new ObjectId so below query deleted only given object Id

```
db.collectioName.remove({"_id":new ObjectId("xxxssssx")})
```

or simply try this

```
db.collectioName.remove({"_id": ObjectId("xxxssssx")})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot update an id [How update the _id of one MongoDB Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document)
You should delete your documents and insert them again as code below do this.

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(item)
{
    if(typeof item._id == 'object')
    {                  
        var id = item._id.toString().replace('ObjectId(', '').replace(')', '');               
        db.test.remove({'_id': item._id});

        item._id = id;
        db.test.insert(item);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `$type` operator. The `type` of `Object Id` is `7`.

```
 db.collection.remove({"_id":{$type:7}})
```

This removes all the documents having the `_id` fields represented as `Object Ids`.