# How does Mongo's findOneAndReplace deal with ids?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm referring to the Mongo Node driver's [findOneAndReplace](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndReplace) method.

Two questions:

1. Is it true that you can't pass a replacement object with an `_id` property? It wasn't working when I was passing that property, and started working when I removed the property.
2. When the object gets replaced in the database, what will the `_id` of the new object be? For me it seems that it's the same as the old `_id`, but I'm not sure if there are situations where this won't be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is true, this is a fundamental design property of MongoDB. You cannot, for reasons of sharding and what not, change the `_id` in the document. You must replace the document, for reference: [How update the _id of one MongoDB Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document)
2. The same as the old `_id`, the `_id` never changes in a document.

Comment: I have a tangential question that I'm curious about - how does 2) work? I thought that it's actually creating a new document, and that when new documents are created it generates some `_id` that has never been used before.

Comment: @AdamZerner it doesn't create a new document it updates the old one with new contents. Even when you replace the contents of the document you don't actually replace the document. It is a bit deceptive I know but the _id is a constant within any document

Comment: @AdamZerner Ok I just double checked a sec and "replace" is a really bad word to use here. It is mega confusing but after reading the documentation is essentially FindAnyModify but it replaces the contents of the document excluding _id since MongoDB does not allow that. There is an upsert option in the function for upserting a new document but otherwise it will not replace the actual document with a new _id