# how can I reset broken _ids

Tags: mongodb

I have imported my database entries from a csv file into mongodb and in the process of doing so the imported entries's '_id's aren't in the typical randomised format. e.g instead of looking like

```
"_id": "R6AnePqKecNNe7dkr"
```

they look like

```
"_id": 28
```

For some reason this means that when I try to refer to the database entry with an _id of 28 it can't find it. I thought it might be an issue in that they _id is not a string because they're not in quotes but I've tried to convert them to strings and that doesn't make a difference. I've tried making a function that randomly generates a new _id but it can't find the old _id to put the new _id into.

Is there any way to do a bulk "generate new _ids for everything in this collection"? I'm having trouble finding anything equivalent

Comment: There's nothing wrong with numerical `_id` values as long as they're all unique. `db.test.findOne({_id: 28})` would find it.

Comment: thanks for your help! my problem was that I was getting the id as a parameter from the URL which was a string and since the _id wasn't a string I had to convert it into a number before using it in findOne

Comment: Did you fix that or still in trouble?

Comment: @profesor79 thanks, all fixed - the problem ended up being unrelated to how I phrased the question

Comment: FYI: the `_id` field is immutable, so to change to a new value you need to copy affected documents and re-insert with a new (or empty) `_id` similar to [How update the _id of one MongoDB Document?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4012997).