# Mongoose how to stop using _id (don't store it) and use id instead

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Since I will be listing my full database on `/bots`, and I want to use id instead of _id (discord uses id for everything, so I'm accustomed with id and not _id)
I don't even want to save id as _id in the database. So any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible!

MongoDB automatically creates an _id for every document that gets inserted into a database.
This is there in order to give you a one-to-one value that you will be able to use to identify each document.

The id also contains a timestamp to when you inserted the document which then can be used to optimize queries using indexes.

This is also a best practice to send the `_id` to the user (even if it's mapped to an `id` field) to then be able to query more efficiently and also to not expose their Discord Id to everyone.

Hope I could answer your question.
You could read more about it here:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field
- [How to remove _id in MongoDB and replace with another field as a Primary Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381231/how-to-remove-id-in-mongodb-and-replace-with-another-field-as-a-primary-key)

Comment: Ok, but I found a good way for _id. Instead of sending random letters (objectId, the way mongodb says, I used `new Date` which is quite useful instead of old thingy. And I use id for discord stuff.