# Cannot change _id field in Mongo DB from int to objectId using foreach

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Unfortunatelly all my Mongo collections have _id as integer, instead of Object ID. I'm trying to amend that with Robomongo client, and I'm trying with that command:

```
db.getCollection('client').find({}).forEach(function(doc){
  var doc2 = doc;
  doc2._id = new ObjectId(); 
  db.collection1.insert(doc2);
});
```

Unfortunatelly the documents are not inserted or changed, although I get this output:

```
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
 Inserted 1 record(s) in 1ms
```

How should I change the command above to make it working?

Comment: Why not just `delete doc._id; db.collection1.insert(doc);` ? btw how do you check if they were inserted? I can't reproduce tbh.

Comment: Are you trying to _only_ update your `client` collection or copy items from `client` to `collection1` ? Because currently you are copying items in `client` to `collection1` and updating there _id in the same time .. Not sure that what you wanted

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16951488) by Patrick Wolf will work for you.

Comment: I just need to change the field _id from int to objectId