# Is ObjectId in mongodb a constant?

Tags: mongodb

Is ObjectId in mongodb a constant or can it change after the creation of the document?

Can update or any other operation change it?

My ObjectId seems to have changed for a couple of documents and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way that your object ID would have changed.

The reason being is Since the object ID is created on the following : 
Year ,
month,
Date ,
Hours,
Minutes,
Seconds.
So, there is Absolutely NO Way in which your _id would have changed.

Moreover refer the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document) , you can't even Update the object id. Its created by mongoDb for every insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `_id` field (if that's what you mean by ObjectId) is read-only. Other fields of type ObjectId are fully mutable, of course.

> My ObjectId seems to have changed for a couple of documents and I cannot figure out why.

Impossible. But, you can create a **new** document, which is a copy of another document, has all the same fields, but id is different. Then you delete the original document. Et voila, document *appears* to have id changed.

Check your code, maybe something like that can happen.