# Can I update the exsisting record of mongodb by its id?

Tags: mongodb

I just want to know that how will I update the existing record `_id` by its `_id`. It means that suppose there is a record and that having an `objectId` given like below:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b3b5607638ea66f51508913"),
```

And I want to update this id into a integer. I also read the mongodb documentation of [updation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) but it only update the other field how will I update the id to the integer form like `"_id" : 1,` this. Is there any method of doing this.

Comment: @ansh No, you can't. You must to create a new document and remove the old one. Take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document

Comment: You can update BY id. You can't update THE id. It's two different questions.