# findOneAndUpdate doesn't create ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to make a patch request to update only one (or several) field(s) at the same time.
I've got a big object which is my document, and inside nested array of objects.

For example, for my car array, this is the schema :

```
const carSchema = new Schema({
  owner: [{value: {type: String}, label: {type: String}}],
  carPlate: {type: String},
  carColor: {type: String},
  carBrand: {type: String},
  carStatus: {type: String}
});

const myObject = new Schema({
...
cars: [carSchema]
...
});
```

When I send my changes, I do it this way :

let dynamicVar = 'cars.'+i+'.'+myfield;
this.props.updateGeneral({_id: this.props.general._id, [dynamicVar ]: [myfield.value]});

I'm on redux, so my action looks like :

```
export function updateGeneral(data) {
    let _id = data._id;
    delete data._id;
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_GENERAL',
        payload: client.patch(`${url}/${_id}`, data)
    }
}
```

And my PATCH request is like :

```
router.patch('/url/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
myObject.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: req.body }, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, objectReturn) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    cn = cn.substr(0, cn.indexOf(' {'));
    res.json(objectReturn);

  });
});
```

My BIG issue is that my field is update or inserted, but if it's inserted and it creates a new array it won't create the objectId linked. It won't even create the array of object,just an object with a property.

How can I make mongoose initiates ObjectId??

Comment: Please format your post better.

Comment: It is not possible to upsert with mongodb ObjectId... An objectId is auto generated field and cannot be used in upsertion

Answer (score 0):

Per the reply to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document) it looks like you cannot update object IDs. When doing so, you are effectively "deleting" the object and creating a new one.