# Is it possible to change the data type of a mongodb object? Specific change from object to string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to change a MongoDB object id data type to string.

Comment: You'll likely have to go through the app. Fetch the document, make whatever mutations/transformations you need and save the document back.

Comment: if it is object type but not the document _id  you can just update with the new value without issues , if it is the document _id it is abit more complicated check here a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-to-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.