# Is there a way to create MongoDB document with an exist _id that is nested in the document

Tags: c#, mongodb, guid

I have a collection of documents, and there is one thing that is common for all documents - an ID field that is nested.

Document for example:

```
{
    "_id": <generated guid>
    "item": {
        "product": {
            "id": <guid>
            .. more fields
        }
    },
    "source": "Good Store"
}
```

I would like to set (at creation) the `_id` guid to be the guid that inside the product's scope. **Is that possible?**

I tried to search for it and didn't found an answer.

When I tried to map the object (using C#), I got an error that indicates that I can't map a nested field to the Id field.

Comment: no afaik, but you can have a separate nested id if you need to

Comment: @dododo I just know the desired ID of the document and can't set it to that ID. Maybe do you know the reason for that?

Comment: see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/document/#field-names

Comment: in 2 words it's immutable reserved field

Comment: @dododo I know that I can change the id field to a value that I generate. The problem is with nested value from some reason

Comment: you can't modify `_id`, you can only generate a custom _id during inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following options:

1.

```
    db.coll.updateMany(
       { },
       [   
          { $addFields: { a : 10 } },   // just example, you need to get a data from some other document 
                                        // and then you can add him as "_id" with `upsert: true`. 
                                        // This _id should not present in the collection before
          { $set: { "_id": "$a" } },    // because it's upsert=true and such _id is not in the collection yet
                                        // the actually inserted _id will be value in `$a`
       ],
       { upsert: true }
    )
```

2. Use diff collection and $out stage:

   ```
    MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.coll.insertOne({ "_id": 1, "item": { "product": { "id": 11 } },   "source": "Good Store" }) // your current case
    { "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : 1 }
    MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.coll.aggregate( [ { $set: { _id : "$item.product.id" }}, { $out: "coll2" } ]) // inserting _id you want for the coll2
    MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.coll2.find() // check that _id is changed
    { "_id" : 11, "item" : { "product" : { "id" : 11 } }, "source" : "Good Store" }
   ```

you can also make aggregation output into current collection, but pay attention that $out actually removes all content in your collection and replaces it by aggregate result

3. also you can use approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012855/how-to-update-the-id-of-one-mongodb-document) where you save a new document with updated _id and remove the old one

Comment: About 1 - Is it possible to update the _id field? I can't do that with c# driver and even with the shell on google the answer is no.

Comment: no, as I wrote above this value is immutable. In #1, the key point that `upsert=true` and this is a new document for collection. In this case when `upsert=true`, effectively happened operation is `insert`, not `update`